# The proof of K4-minor free is Class 1.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I find a result that "if a graph G is K4-minor free with ∆ ≥ 3 then the chromatic index χ′(G) ≤ ∆ (G is belongs to Class 1)", but I cannot find the proof of it.
It is about edge coloring.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.